# How to delete a permission set from multiple users?

Tags: user-management, permission-sets

Please let me know the steps to delete a permission set from 3500 users

Answer (score 4):

You have to delete junction object of permision set - PermissionSetAssignment.

```
Set<Id> userIds = new Set<Id>();
/** fill ths set Ids of users you want delete permission set **/
yourPermissionSetId = [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE Name = /** your Permission Set Name**/ LIMIT 1].Id;

delete [SELECT Id 
        FROM PermissionSetAssignment 
        WHERE AssigneeId IN : userIds AND PermissionSetId = : yourPermissionSetId];
```